# Change in Date Format

Tags: javascript, date

I am ploting a chart using google annotated timeline chart
https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#annotated_time_line

I am getting my data through ajax call in json format in an array like this

```
d[1][0] = 9/30/04, d[2][0] = 12/31/04
```

i have to loop through these values to add to data rows

```
for (m = 1; m < datavalues.length; m++) {
    data.addRows('DATE', parseFloat(datavalues[m][2]), parseFloat(datavalues[m][3]), parseFloat(datavalues[m][4]), parseFloat(datavalues[m][5])]);
}
```

But code accepts format like

```
[new Date(2008, 1 ,1), 30000, null, null, 40645, null, null]
```

So how to change the format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you start with date in format `9/30/04`, which seems something like `mm/dd/yy`, then all you need is to separate those values with `split` function

```
var inputDate = '9/30/04',
    splitDate = inputDate.split('/'); // => ["9", "30", "04"]
```

After that, you need to prepare year, month and day numbers

```
var inputDate = '9/30/04',
    splitDate = inputDate.split('/'),
    year = parseInt(splitDate[2]) + (parseInt(splitDate[2]) < 50 ? 2000 : 1900), // careful with this, I don't know what years you are dealing with
    month = parseInt(splitDate[0]),
    day = parseInt(splitDate[1]);
```

And use them as parameters to create new `Date` object

```
var inputDate = '9/30/04',
    splitDate = inputDate.split('/'),
    year = parseInt(splitDate[2]) + (parseInt(splitDate[2]) < 50 ? 2000 : 1900),
    month = parseInt(splitDate[0]),
    day = parseInt(splitDate[1]),
    date = new Date(year, month, day); // => Date {Sat Oct 30 2004 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (FLE Standard Time)}
```

You just need to make sure, that format remains the same `mm/dd/yy`. I would make some sort of date conversion function, that takes input date in specific format and returns date object.

Use this date object in your chart options.